# Using ftp_nb_get seems to stop downloading

Tags: php, ftp

I using ftp_nb_get to download a file from FTP to a local text file. This is done according to following code:

```
 $file_raw="temp_file_raw.txt";
set_time_limit(500000); 

$remote_file_size=ftp_size($conn_id, $_POST['file_name']);
$ret=ftp_nb_get($conn_id,$file_raw , $_POST['file_name'], FTP_BINARY);
while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
    echo ((filesize($file_raw)/$remote_file_size)*100)."<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
}
```

The problem is that is will print 0.10112359550562 every time and the download never finished. I think this number should change if the downloading works, right?  Anyone with an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Have solved it by my one. The fix was to add a  clearstatcache();
before echo ((filesize($file_raw)/$remote_file_size)*100)."<br>";. Then it was seen that the precent actully changed and it just took very long time to download.